Key not invalidated by new biometric enrollment
I am creating a key used for login via biometrics with this method
 fun createKey() {
        val mKeyStore: KeyStore
        val mKeyGenerator: KeyGenerator
        val androidKeyStore = "AndroidKeyStore"
        val keyName = "my_key"
   
        try {
            mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(androidKeyStore)
            mKeyStore.load(null)
            mKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, androidKeyStore)
            mKeyGenerator.init(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setKeySize(256)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationParameters(0,KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
                .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
                .build())
            mKeyGenerator.generateKey()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, e.message, e)
        }
    }

And calling it in the onAuthenticationSucceeded of the BiometricPrompt.
However, adding a new fingerprint is not invalidating the previously created key and forcing the user to re enter their credentials. Is something wrong with my implementations?
